# fetch dynamoDB results ordered by sort key with node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have primary_key ('id'/string) and sort_key ('updated_at'/Unix time stamp number). When I query to dynamo DB trough lambda using node.j, I want to fetch results ordered by my sort_key.

I have tried scan but results are not ordered during scan calls. When I do the query it requires to do an operation with my primary key. How can I fetch my data sorted by sort key?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you have a composite primary key comprising `id` plus `updated_at`. With this type of key you can `query` for records with a given `id`, sorted by `updated_at`.

If you want to sort purely by `updated_at`, then you need to add a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on `updated_at`. This would require the value of `updated_at` to be unique for each item.

Comment: looks like what ive been looking for ill accept the answer as soon as I confirm. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Be sure to understand what attribute projection means (at that same page). You'll need to decide which attributes to project into the GSI.